# Catching the AltGr key with Application.Onkey

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a program using VBA in Excel 2019 and I'm trying to reassign a key combination with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

I'm using a german keyboard layout. This layout has the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key instead of the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key present on US keyboards. From what I've read, Windows will treat <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>. At first glance, this seems to be true. Firing up Excel (or any other application that allows text input) and pressing either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> will give me the `€` currency symbol, as expected.

Now consider the following code:

```
Sub Test()
Application.OnKey "^%e", "Test2"
End Sub

Sub Test2()
Call MsgBox("Hey you!")
End Sub
```

Here's the problem I'm unable to solve: pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> will display the MsgBox, but pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> will still write the `€` symbol to the active cell. It seems that `AltGr` does not get caught with `^%`, even though it should in fact be the same thing as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

How do I catch <kbd>AltGr</kbd> with `Application.Onkey`?